# Regent of the Castle November competition

Tags: discussion, fun, unanswered-questions

In an effort to change up the monthly answering competition, I introduce the 'King of the Castle' format.

Rules:

Day 0: Nobody is Regent. The Game of throne begins.

Continuous:

Answer a question posted before March 31, 2019.
Get an upvote.
Add it to the answer below.
You become the 'Regent'.

Repeat.

Whoever is the 'Regent' at the end of November wins the competition.

Dethroning: If your upvoted answer is invalidated (question is closed, answer loses its votes, is determined to not fit the old question criteria), you are dethroned and the previous Regent retakes the throne.  If there is no previous regent, the throne is vacant.

Please add a comment below if clarifications are required, and indicate if you're keen to compete.

Comment: Is it just a matter of being the last Regent at 23:59:59 on the last day?

Comment: Does the answer need a positive votes saldo or are upvotes (even if fewer than downvotes) enough?

Comment: So as @JoErNanO said, it's basically pointless until the last day?

Comment: Hmm. I presumed people would want to compete during the month but fair point @JoErNanO.  What about if we changed it to 'most successful answers' (upvotes).  @

Comment: @Willeke positive value.  Should have a score of 1+

Comment: We need to find a way to reward something other than answering for the sake of getting one upvotes IMHO. We need some form of increasingly harder metric to beat within a fixed timeframe. Gotta think this over.

Comment: @JoErNanO how about the first regent only needs 1 upvote. Second person requires a score of 2 to unseat them . 3rd requires a score of 3 on an answer, etc

Comment: @MarkMayo I thought of that. Problem is it becomes very hard to beat very quickly: how many competition answers got more than 5 votes? 10 votes? I think history shows most answers stay at 1-2 votes. Especially for old question answerathon. We might have to tweak the calculation formula sightly.

Comment: Becomes hard to beat, but that might encourage you to try more with multiple answers.

Comment: @JoErNanO perhaps you need - if x is the current score, you need (x+1)/day of month, which makes it a little easier as the month progresses

Comment: How about not making it a monthly event but always ongoing? No need to go for higher rep. Just a pride thing.

Comment: @Willeke not bad, could just make an ongoing 'Regent of Travel' for whoever sucessfully answered the last oldest unanswered question.

Comment: @MarkMayo, that is the last who posted their upvoted answer. So you may need to put something in the rules that only the most recent answered (or is it upvoted) answer counts.

Comment: @Willeke correct, true. It'd just be in the wording, but not too hard to do.

Comment: @JoErNanO thoughts?

Comment: Only the user receiving rep knows when it was received. Makes it hard to review acceptable answers due to vote timing.

Comment: The time answered may need to be the deciding time. So answer, wait for an upvote, go to competition page, compare time answered with the most recent, and if yours is newer, post it.

Comment: Or we do it based on the day only, rather than the time. First person to meet criteria on the day gets it, and you can't usurp until the following day?

Comment: Are we starting this one?

Comment: ... are we waiting for someone to claim the first regency?

Comment: I don't understand why this is selected as *featured* when nobody seems to think the rules are sensible or have any interest in participating.

Comment: I think we just need to add the clarification on how someone unseats the current regent

Comment: I like the idea but it needs slightly harder rules to avoid gaming the competition too much.

Comment: closing for now to work on rules

Comment: @ChrisH We were trying to gather attention from Travel.SE members in order to brainstorm the rules.